# Check if a string is equal or substring of another

Tags: java, string, indexof

I am trying to check if one string is the same as another or maybe if it's a part of it with the code below:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Comparison {

    static void compare() throws FileNotFoundException {

        Scanner queries = new Scanner(new FileReader("./out.txt"));
        Scanner folks = new Scanner(new FileReader("./tal.txt"));
        int index1 = 0;
        while ( queries.hasNextLine() ){
            String check = queries.next();

            while (folks.hasNextLine()) {
                String toCheck = folks.next();
                index1 = toCheck.indexOf(check);
            }//while
        }//while

        System.out.println("Result: "+ index1);
    }
}
```

But I get the error below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:838)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1347)
    at results.Comparison.compare(Comparison.java:28)
    at results.Main.main(Main.java:42)
```

What is the problem? How can I make it work?

Comment: You're sure you reference the correct file? Referencing files external to the classpath just with `./[...]` is dangerous.

Comment: static void compare() throws FileNotFoundException      file reference is correct...

Comment: Btw: your comparison is interesting - it will only print the last occuring hit found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initialization of `folks` needs to be inside the outer loop, for example:

```
        Scanner queries = new Scanner(new FileReader("./out.txt"));
        int index1 = 0;
        while ( queries.hasNextLine() ){
            String check = queries.next();
            Reader r = new FileReader("./tal.txt");
            try {
                Scanner folks = new Scanner(r);
                while (folks.hasNextLine()) {
                    String toCheck = folks.next();
                    index1 = toCheck.indexOf(check);
                    if (index1 >= 0) {
                        // Do something with index1 here?
                    }
                }//while
            } finally {
                r.close();
            }
        }//while
```

Comment: now i take the error below:     Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: ./NetBeansProjects/Results/tags_disticts_opacial.txt (Too many open files)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:106)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:66)
 at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:41)
 at results.Comparison.compare(Comparison.java:27)
 at results.Main.main(Main.java:42)

Comment: @user758084, I'm slightly surprised you get that error, but I've updated the code to ensure all readers are closed ASAP.  Try it now.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use nextLine(), not next().
As in:

```
String check = queries.nextLine();
```

and:

```
String toCheck = folks.nextLine();
```

Because the default delimiter is whitespace, if you have a blank line at the end of the file (and maybe other things), there may not be a next(), even though hasNextLine() returned true.  Always use the hasNext*() method corresponding to the next*() that you're using - (and vice versa ;-)).